# StreamReader Gets Stuck on Large Files

Tags: c#, streamreader, large-files

I'm trying to read a 50GB text file with a streamreader. It doesn't even get to reading the file, because my program freezes on the second line(of code, not the file).

```
string filename = @"C:\wikipedia\dump.xml";
StreamReader wikipediaReader = new StreamReader(filename);
string line = "";
while((line = wikipediaReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure its frozen and not working? If you put long running operations on the main thread the program will appear frozen.

Comment: @eddie_cat It gets stuck on the second line. I left it for about half an hour.

Comment: Does your code work with a small test file?

Comment: Are you sure it's not waiting for you to hit a key?

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes, and it worked fine.

Comment: When you leave it running, does your process memory usage increase?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Nope! Stays under 100MB.

Comment: @MarkLarter Not sure. I don't understand why it would change anything, it doesn't even get to reading the file.

Comment: Is there any chance that the file is locked in some way? Like maybe it is open in an editor or something.

Comment: What happens if you first open the file as a READONLY stream and then attach the streamreader to that stream?

Comment: @Stilgar No, I have renamed the file as a test.

Comment: @lboshuizen What do you mean? How do I do that?

Comment: I was wondering, if the file contains Unix newlines instead of Windows newlines, would @JoelCoehoorn's comment nail it?

Comment: @user1599078 see my temporary(!) answer

Comment: I would break and look at the call stack and see where it is that it is stuck inside of the `StreamReader` constructor. That might give us a clue.

Comment: This is your anti-malware software getting involved.  No, you cannot see it from the call stack, it is off in the woods trying to figure out what to do with 50 jiggabytes of potential malware.

Comment: @HansPassant why would it be scanning an XML file?

Comment: @HansPassant Wouldn't we see an exception because the file was locked or inaccessible in that case?

Comment: I should probably tell you that when I run your code or my code, the only way to stop the program is to log out and back in. I've tried task manager, ending the process tree, and command prompt.

Comment: @user - XML files are very good at hosing your machine, any anti-malware will put them on the top of the list.  Their DTD is a great DoS attack.

Comment: @user1599078 What does taskmanager tell you about diskactivity or cpu?

Comment: File extensions like xml are a convenience, not a definitive statement about what's in a file. How does the antivirus software know it's really just xml unless it looks?

Comment: Anyway, would it hurt to try this with the AV software disabled, or with an exemption for the file?

Comment: @lboshuizen CPU idle, HDD heavy read.

Comment: Then very likely something is reading the file, either the Framework or indeed some AV software. @HansPassant could certainly have a point here

Comment: Trying it out with the AV disabled. Give me a sec...

Comment: Well, there you go.  Who needs a virus when the anti-dote is indistinguishable from the problem.  At least mention the name so everybody learns what to avoid.

Comment: @HansPassant Since we have a solution, you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Hans please tell us how you knew that was the problem.

Comment: I applied Occam's razor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be anti-virus software trying to scan the file.

Comment: Community Wiki so I don't take credit for @HansPassant's work. I just wanted to get this out here as a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read file

Answer (score -1):

we have to use splitter and set the start position and endposition while reading the file

i advice you to check [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189270/tracking-the-position-of-the-line-of-a-streamreader).

if you still have issue , please let me know i will help you with the working code