# C# upload file to client, I need a progress function server side in ASP.NET Core 7 Web API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

This method allows you to download files larger than 10 GB; is there a server side way to check the progress? Or is there a way to determine how many transfers to clients are active?

```
public IActionResult GetFile(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");
        }
                
        Console.WriteLine(retMessage);

        return NotFound(retMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Comment: `FileStreamResult` does not provide a built-in way to check the progress of the file transfer. I'm not sure if there has any third-party plugin can achieve it.

Comment: instead of the FileStreamResult object can I use another object that supports the progress and download of large files?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189270/tracking-the-position-of-the-line-of-a-streamreader)